# How to select which Input/Output device being used by waveIn/waveOut functions C++

Tags: c++, wav

I have been looking into the `waveIn` functions for sound recording, I can record for a set length of time but I have an issue with the input/output devices that are used.

I have no idea how to select which input or output device the functions should use, I know waveInOpen takes a deviceID as its second parameter but I have only used `WAVE_MAPPER` here and I think this just selects the first device that supports the format chosen.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could lend me a hand or at least point me in the right direction to understand how to get the device ID of a specific input/output device or however it is supposed to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call [`waveInGetNumDevs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd743844.aspx) to tell you how many devices are available on the system. The valid identifiers are the integers from 0 to N-1 (where N is the number that `waveInGetNumDevs` returned).

You can then use [`waveInGetDevCaps`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd743841.aspx) to get information about each available input device. This will give you the product name, number of channels, and the formats it supports ([and a few other things](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743839.aspx)). You could (for one obvious example) use that to fill a list, and let the user choose from the list.

Then you supply the identifier for the chosen device when you call `waveInOpen`.

Comment: Ah right, I hadn't realised the identifiers would be the values you mentioned from waveInGetNumDevs, thought there was some other way of getting a specific handle for each input device. Thank you for the fast and simple explanation :)

Comment: @tmckeown2: I"m not sure if it's there any more, but at least at one time, if you read down through all the documentation for `waveInOpen`, somewhere down in the comments, it mentioned that handy little tidbit.